# How to retrieve the values from the mysql table which are not having default value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the values in the mysql table which are not default values. is there any way to use only sql query without using php?

Comment: do you know the default values in advance? e.g. the default value is 0, do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE columname != 0`?

Comment: what is datatype of that column???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DEFAULT(col_name)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default).

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 != DEFAULT(col1)
```

If you want all rows where at least one column is not the default use `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 != DEFAULT(col1)
OR   col2 != DEFAULT(col2) # etc etc...
```

Or if you want all rows where all the columns are not the default use `AND`.